# invoke Listener from other Listener

Tags: javascript

I have 2 listeners: one invokes another. Question is if second (nested) listener knows where in the document the first listener was triggered? I mean when I use addEventListener for 50 fields in a column and within this listener invoke another listener then the second one 'knows' the position (I mean field where it was clicked) of the first one? I try to cope with this problem - don't know if somehow second listener 'inherits' variables' values from the first one. E.g:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#decisionList").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("change", function () {

    var selectedOptionIndex = this.options[this.selectedIndex].index;
    var invoiceDateText = this.closest('tr').querySelector('.payment').textContent.trim();
    var finalChoice = this.closest('tr').querySelector('.choice');


    switch (selectedOptionIndex) {

        case 0:
            finalChoice.innerHTML = '<input type="date">'
            break;

        case 1:
            finalChoice.innerHTML = '<input id="finalDate" type="date">'
            finalDateListener(selectedOptionIndex, invoiceDateText); //here I'm passing variables keeping current values from main Listener

        default:

            finalChoice.innerHTML = ''

    }}));




function finalDateListener(selectedOptionIndex, invoiceDateText){

const finalDate = document.getElementById("finalDate"); //'id' from parent Listener

    finalDate.addEventListener("change", function () {
        alert(invoiceDateText + ' ' + selectedOptionIndex); 
 });
}
```

This code works only for first triggering of second listener (so when I invoke first listener and after that the second one), for the next ones it doesn't work, no alerts shows up. Does that mean that I need to again look for closest element in second listener?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Ids are expected to be unique within the document, by web standards.  The id you are looking up is not relative to the parent listener, but the entire document, and will only return one, the very first one

Comment: Yes, but the question is how I can change it in my code, to make id relative to the parent listener. I tried many things but in vain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the new input element using `document.createElement` instead of by typing a string in `innerHTML`, then you can pass on the new input element to your second function and you don't need an `id` at all.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#decisionList").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    console.log("you clicked " + event.target)
    var finalChoice = event.target.closest('tr').querySelector('.choice')
    var inputElement = document.createElement("input")
    inputElement.type = "date"
    finalChoice.appendChild(inputElement)
    finalDateListener(inputElement, selectedOptionIndex, invoiceDateText)
}))

function finalDateListener(element, selectedOptionIndex, invoiceDateText){
    console.log("the new input element is " + element)
    element.addEventListener("change", ()=> {
        console.log("changed")
    })
    
}
```

Comment: but it doesn't work. When use event.target in child Listener I have an error in a console: ```Site.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at finalDateListener (Site.js:78)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (Site.js:61)```

Comment: OK, I updated the answer. You can create a new input element using `createElement`. That element can be passed on to the next function.